# how to find more than one match with a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

i have a string like this:

```
to_search = "example <a>first</a> asdqwe <a>second</a>"
```

and i want to find both solutions between   like this:

```
list = ["first","second"]
```

i know that when searching for one solution i should use this code:

```py
import re

if to_search.find("<a>") > -1:
    result = re.search('<a>(.*?)</a>', to_search)
    s = result.group(1)
    print(s)
```

but that only prints:

```
first
```

i tried result.group(2) and result.group(0) but i get the same solution

how can i make a list of all solutions?

Comment: "Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead."

Comment: Whether or not you were using HTML didn't seem relevant to me, you were still trying to extract html from a string, to which the correct answer is use a html parser

Comment: no, my question is **not** about _extracting html_ , my question is about regex inside a string. and the correct answer is **not**   _use an html praser_ , the answer is use `re.findall` as answered [by @Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58326242/12160728) . using an html parser on another string with "(a)" instead of "<a>" would not work. thank you

Comment: also the same string that i used is written in the python documentations under [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) i did not use <a> just because i like html or anything. "<a>" is literally written in the python documentation for the Regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
import re
to_search = "example <a>first</a> asdqwe <a>second</a>"
matches = re.findall(r'<a>(.*?)</a>', to_search)
print(matches)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['first', 'second']
```

Answer (score 1):

best to use a HTML parser than regex, but change `re.search` to `re.findall`

Answer (score 0):

```
to_search = "example <a>first</a> asdqwe <a>second</a>"
for match in re.finditer("<a>(.*?)</a>", to_search):
    captured_group = match.group(1)
    # do something with captured group
```